# Unable to delete broken kernel packages

Tags: package-management, kernel, boot-partition

I am running Kubuntu having trouble removing two broken kernel packages that prevent me from updating or installing any other packages.

I have tried to remove them through synaptics I get the following result:

```
(synaptic:934): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en:sv:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_SE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 387112 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic (3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_NcsIXF/lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_NcsIXF/lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-77-generic (3.16.0-77.99~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-77-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-77-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-77-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-77-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-77-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-77-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_xOjzhJ/lib/modules/3.16.0-77-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_xOjzhJ/lib/modules/3.16.0-77-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-77-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-77-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-77-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

I have also tried removing both packages with

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic
```

Then I get this result:

```
larran@larran-VPCSB1V9E:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic
[sudo] password for larran: 
(Reading database ... 387112 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic (3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_KhGV8U/lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_KhGV8U/lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-53-generic
```

I don't know what to do. I really don't feel like reinstalling.

After running df I get the following:

```
larran@larran-VPCSB1V9E:~$ df
Filesystem                   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                           1964816         4   1964812   1% /dev
tmpfs                           396104      1224    394880   1% /run
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root 476249128 299972776 152061212  67% /
none                                 4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                              5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                           1980516        76   1980440   1% /run/shm
none                            102400        20    102380   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                       240972    234895         0 100% /boot
```

Comment: How big is your hard disk, and how much free space do you have? In terminal, type **df** and paste the output here for us to see. Cheers, Al

Comment: See the result in edited question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running LVM, and your /boot partition is full. Increase this partition size, or remove unnecessary files (like old kernels, etc.) from /boot.

Go to the dash and start **Logical Volume Management** to view your partitions. If you don't see that in the dash, you'll have to install **system-config-lvm** using Synaptic.

Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks, but this this is only part of the problem. /boot partition is full because of the two broken kernels i mentioned earlier that cannot be deleted. These packages also stop me from updating or installing anything at all. Even if I increase the size of the /boot partition the broken packages will still cause trouble?

Comment: Once you get /boot resized, you'll probably be able to work with the broken stuff. We won't know if you'll still have problems deleting stuff and reinstalling/upgrading until we try. Cheers, Al